Getting error Iin VASP caclulation while i am trying to run PBE-SOC Bandstrucutre calculation
The error message is:
=====================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   RANK 0 PID 1670618 RUNNING AT cn03
=   KILLED BY SIGNAL: 9 (Killed)
=====================================================================

My INCAR file is:
    #Self-consistent calculation
    ISTART = 0
    PREC = Normal
    LREAL = Auto
    ALGO = Normal
    # Electronic relaxation:
    ENCUT = 500.00
    EDIFF = 1E-04 stopping-criterion for ELM
    #BMIX = 1.0
    #NELM = 1
    #TIME = 0.05
    #ALGO = NORMAL
    #NBANDS = 200
    #LHFCALC = .TRUE.
    #HFSCREEN = 0.2
    #LUSE_VDW = .TRUE.
    #AGGAC = 0.000000
    #GGA = OR
    #LASPH = .TRUE.
    # Ionic relxation:
    #IBRION = 2
    #EDIFFG = -0.01
    #NSW = 100
    #ISIF = 3
    # POTIM = 0.1
    # DOS related parameters:
    ISMEAR = -1
    SIGMA = 0.01
    NCORE = 4
    #NGX = 18
    #NGY = 18
    LORBIT = 11
    ICHARG = 11
    # Spin-polarized calculations:
    # ISPIN = 2
    # Write wavefunctions and charge densities
    LWAVE= .TRUE.
    #LOPTICS = .TRUE.
    #CSHIFT = 0.01
    #NEDOS = 2000
    #NOMEGA=100
    #OMEGAMAX=20
    #OMEGATL=260
    #Spin-Orbit Coupling Calculation
    LSORBIT    = .TRUE.    (Activate SOC)
    GGA_COMPAT = .FALSE.   (Apply spherical cutoff on gradient field)
    ##VOSKOWN    =  1        (Enhances the magnetic moments and the magnetic energies)
    LMAXMIX    =  4        (For d elements increase LMAXMIX to 4, f: LMAXMIX = 6)
    ISYM       =  -1       (Switch symmetry off)
    AMIX = 0.1
    BMIX = 0.01


This is what is written to stderr, right? Is there anything interesting written to stdout or to OUTCAR?

this is written at the end of Outcar."
parallel 3D FFT for wavefunctions:
minimum data exchange during FFTs selected (reduces bandwidth)
parallel 3D FFT for charge:
minimum data exchange during FFTs selected (reduces bandwidth)
"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My point is that error message in stderr could be from any number of problems ranging from VASP crashing for some reason to you not compiling the code correctly. Are there any useful error messages in OUTCAR or stdout?

IIRC, that message ^ is printed while initializing wave function arrays. Without any more information, I am going to guess you ran out of memory. Try using more memory or decreasing ENCUT and seeing if it runs successfully. See here if you are in fact running out of memory: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Not_enough_memory
